# Proof that if convex polyhedron doesn't contain triangles and quadrangles then $3m \le 5n - 10$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Proof that if convex polyhedron doesn't contain triangles and quadrangles then $3m \le 5n - 10$ where $m$ is number of edges and $n$ number of vertices

I don't know how to start this task but I suspect that there is something similar with planar graphs. If planar graph doesn't contain cycle with length $<r$ then we have 
$$ rf \le 2m \\
rf = 2r - nr  + mr \\
(r-2)m \le r(n-2) $$
so in our case for $r=5$ it will be
$$ 3m \le 5n - 10 $$

But I don't know if each convex polyhedron is planar graph. Is that true? I did find anything about that in my lecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using more traditional letters, let $v,e,f$ denote the number of *vertices*, the number of *edges*, and the number of *faces*, respectively.

The key tool is Euler's formula
$$v-e+f=2$$
If we count the edges one face at a time, each edge is counted twice, hence
$$2e = 5f_5+6f_6+7f_7 + \cdots$$
where $f_k$ denotes the number of faces with exactly $k$ edges.

But clearly
$$f=f_5+f_6+f_7 + \cdots$$
hence $2e \ge 5f$, or equivalently, $f\le \frac{2}{5}e$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&v-e+f=2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&e=v+f-2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&e\le  v + {\small{\frac{2}{5}}}e -2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&{\small{\frac{3}{5}}}e\le  v -2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&3e\le 5v-10\\[4pt]
\end{align*}